# Seizing naming master from child domain server

Tags: active-directory

when I am trying to seize the role from my child domain server the naming master I get the following error

```
fsmo maintenance: seize naming master
Attempting safe transfer of domain naming FSMO before seizure.
ldap_modify_sW error 0x34(52 (Unavailable).
Ldap extended error message is 000020AF: SvcErr: DSID-03210380, problem 5002 (UN
AVAILABLE), data 8438

Win32 error returned is 0x20af(The requested FSMO operation failed. The current
FSMO holder could not be contacted.)
)
Depending on the error code this may indicate a connection,
ldap, or role transfer error.
Transfer of domain naming FSMO failed, proceeding with seizure ...
Server "win-fb20ixk90mu" knows about 5 roles
Schema - CN=NTDS Settings,CN=WIN-3918XHC5STU,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Na
me,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=HCL,DC=com
Naming Master - CN=NTDS Settings,CN=WIN-FB20IXK90MU,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-
Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=HCL,DC=com
PDC - CN=NTDS Settings,CN=WIN-FB20IXK90MU,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,
CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=HCL,DC=com
RID - CN=NTDS Settings,CN=WIN-FB20IXK90MU,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,
CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=HCL,DC=com
Infrastructure - CN=NTDS Settings,CN=WIN-FB20IXK90MU,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First
-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=HCL,DC=com
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a long time since I've had to seize a FSMO role, but I think the error you're seeing isn't actually an error as such.

When you try and seize a role, ntdsutil first tries to transfer the role safely, by contacting the role master being demoted. If that fails though, it shows the error, then proceeds to seize the role.

At the end you can see that win-fb20ixk90mu believes that it is the naming master, which says to me that the role seize worked.

Comment: +1. Exactly right. The seizure was successful (after the unsuccessfull graceful transfer) and now win-fb20ixk90mu holds all but the Schema Master role.